# Bootstrap3 inline forms in django-crispy-forms not showing form errors

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) to render a [Bootstrap3 inline form](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-inline-forms) (code shown below), but the errors upon form submission (like skipping required fields) are not being shown. They do in normal and horizontal form layouts.

Could someone please suggest the possible reason(s)?

### Models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

### Forms.py

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.layout.append(ButtonHolder(
            Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary btn-hg')
            )
        )
```

I am using `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` and `{% crispy form %}` in my template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the inline_field.html template that you use, doesn't have a code to display errors.

Please compare normal bootstrap3/field.html to the inline version. You will notice that the

```
{% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
```

is missing in the latter. After you change the inline to something like below you'll have error messages back.

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}

{% if field.is_hidden %}
    {{ field }}
{% else %}
    {% if field|is_checkbox %}
        <div id="div_{{ field.auto_id }}" class="checkbox">
           <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="{% if field.field.required %} requiredField{% endif %}">
                {% crispy_field field 'class' 'checkbox' %}
                {{ field.label|safe }}
                {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
            </label>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div id="div_{{ field.auto_id }}" class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="sr-only{% if field.field.required %} requiredField{% endif %}">
                {{ field.label|safe }}
            </label>
            {% crispy_field field 'placeholder' field.label %}
            {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Of course error messages are quite ugly (as they come from normal version) so you probably have to create inline version of the `bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html`. Also some `error` css classes might be needed - see the field.html.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the current configuration for my projects. I think it might work for you too.

```
#forms.py
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Div
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import  FormActions
from myapp.models import Person

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-entryform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form.method = 'post'
        self.helper.form.action = ''
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div('name','email'),
            Div('country','city'),
            FormActions(Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary btn-hg')
            )
        )
```

Comment: I don't understand. The only difference is see is that you are specifying `form_id`, `method` and `action`, which do have default values. And you are just adding the Submit button to form layout. What about the other fields?

Comment: @user2247606 I edited the answer with the fields. I basically wrap them in a Div, but you can do any configuration you want.

Comment: I'm afraid your code is also not showing the errors.

Comment: @user2247606 I just saw there's a line where you specify a `field_template` but I actually don't have any on my forms. Also make sure you're getting bootstrap3 source right and that it's loading well.

Comment: The inline forms thing is coming from here - http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-inline-forms and the bootstrap3 source is loading fine.

Comment: **Red herring answer.  I don't think this addresses the missing errors question in the least bit.**  It shows an apparently correct configuration for crispy forms, but it has nada to do with the OP's issue.  eXt's answer addresses that issue, although I can't help but think that this is an odd piece of functionality to miss by crispy so maybe we are doing it wrong.