# No error message shown with crispy forms and bootstrap 3

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I have spent hours today trying out and googling, I just can't find the solution for my problem:

I use crispy forms in version 1.4.0 and Bootstrap3. I have a CreateView as shown below which displays a form with the help of crispy forms. The sources for Bootstrap3 seem to load as well. The 'name' field is required.

No matter what I enter in the three fields (or if I leave them completely blank), the form is reloaded every time I hit the "Save" button. No error message appears (e.g. for the required name field).
It seems to have to do with the crispy forms. Because if I leave crispy forms out, I get the "this field is required" message above the name field.

I just don't get it: what am I missing here?
I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863624/bootstrap3-inline-forms-in-django-crispy-forms-not-showing-form-errors), but this does not fit exactly to my case as I don't use the self.helper.field_template variable.

**models.py**

```
class SomeItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Some item name'), max_length=30)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(_('Longitude'), max_digits=9, decimal_places=7, blank=True, null=True,
                                help_text=_('Longitude values range from -90 to 90'))
    latitude = models.DecimalField(_('latitude'), max_digits=9, decimal_places=7, blank=True, null=True,
                                help_text=_('Latitude values range from -180 to 180'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class CrispyForm(ModelForm):
'''
This form serves as a generic form for adding and editing items.
'''
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form_action = kwargs.pop('form_action', None)
    super(CrispyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    # Form attributes
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_action = reverse(form_action)
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'

    # Save button, having an offset to align with field_class
    save_text = _('Save')
    self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save_form', save_text, css_class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2"))


class SomeItemAddForm(CrispyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeItemAddForm, self).__init__(*args, form_action='add-someitem')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class SomeItemAddView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add_someitem.html'
    form_class = SomeItemAddForm
    model = SomeItem
    success_url = reverse_lazy('someitmes')

class ListSomeItemsView(ListView):
    model = SomeItem
    template_name = 'list_someitems.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^someitems/add$', SomeItemAddView.as_view(), name='add-someitem'),
    url(r'^someitems$', ListSomeItemsView.as_view(), name='someitems'),
]
```

**add_someitem.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    {% crispy form %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094974/rendering-field-errors-in-django-crispy-forms-with-inline-forms)?

Comment: The post you mentioned has the same prerequisite: it uses inline-forms. "If I change the helper.field_template to another value (or remove it to set the default) the errors are displayed above each field"
-> this is just not the case in my application, I don't get the errors displayed with the default setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this in the forms.py.

```
class SomeItemAddForm(CrispyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeItemAddForm, self).__init__(*args, form_action='add-someitem', **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

You pass only one kw argument - "form_action", and call the init function of the parent form class without some important kw args. So in general: You pass only the extra keyword argument, and you are forgot the others - from Form, ModelForm, etc ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simeon Popov, now it works and the errors are displayed. Before it seemed that the form was unbound. I didn't know that the parent class expected some arguments from the kwargs-dict as well.